# How to replace a list of strings in a text where some of them are substrings of other?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a text containing some words that I would like to tag, and the words to be tagged are contained in a List. The problem is that some of those words are substrings of others, but I want to tag the longest recognized string from the list.

For example, if my text is "foo and bar are different from foo bar." and my list contains "foo", "bar" and "foo bar" the result should be "[tag]foo[/tag] and [tag]bar[/tag] are different from [tag]foo bar[/tag]."

```
String text = "foo and bar are different from foo bar.";

List<String> words = new ArrayList();
words.add("foo");
words.add("bar");
words.add("foo bar");

String tagged = someFunction(text, words);
```

What should be the code of someFunction in such a way that the value of the string taggedText is `<tag>foo</tag> and <tag>bar</tag> are different from <tag>foo bar</tag>.` ?

Comment: Sort them by length.

Comment: ... and you might use [Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all the matching words with a marker (in my example i used |i| as marker where i corresponds the index of the tagged word.) Try this method:

```
private static String someFunction(String text, List<String> words) {
        //Container for the tagged strings
        List<String> tagged = new ArrayList<>();

        //Create comparator class for sorting list according to string length
        Comparator<String> x = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2)
            {
                if(s1.length() > s2.length())
                    return -1;

                if(s2.length() > s1.length())
                    return 1;

                return 0;
            }
        };

        //Sort list
        Collections.sort(words, x);

        //Replace all words in the text that matches a word in the word list
        //Note that we replace the matching word with a marker |0|, |1|, etc...
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            text = text.replaceAll(words.get(i), "\\|" + i + "\\|");
            //Save the matching word and put it between tags
            tagged.add("<tag>" + words.get(i) + "</tag>");
        }

        //Replace all markers with the tagged words
        for (int i = 0; i < tagged.size(); i++) {
            text = text.replaceAll("\\|" + i + "\\|", tagged.get(i));
        }


        return text;
    }
```

**WARNING:** I'm assuming here that my marker '|i|' will never appear in the text. Replace my marker with any symbols you want that would not appear in the text. This is just an idea, not the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method of String. and compare the each word with List.

```
String somefunction(String text, List<String> words){
  String res = "";
  String[] splits = text.split(" ");
  for(String st: splits){
    if(words.contains(st){
       res += "<tag>"+st+"<\tag>\n";
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a regex that includes each possible word, and a greedy match of one or more or them. Then you can use a matches result from the regex to get each match, and because it's greedy, each match will be the maximum length. The regex itself will depend on your words and what you count for spaces, and whether or not foobar is considered a match for "foo" and "bar".

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework but I'll give you some pointers.

If B is a substring of A, and if B is not equal to A, then B must have a length smaller than the length of A.  You also said it yourself:

> [...] but I want to tag the longest recognized string from the list.

So we have to sort the list of words by length, longest first.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to do that.  `Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)` is what you'll use.

The next problem is the actual replacement.  If you simply loop over all your words and use `String.replaceAll(String, String)`, your example will end up like this:

```
<tag>foo</tag> and <tag>bar</tag> are different from <tag><tag>foo</tag> <tag>bar</tag></tag>.
```

That's because we will first surround 'foo bar' and then we will surround both foo and bar again.  Thankfully, the first parameter of `String.replaceAll(String, String)` is regex.

The trick is to match the word but only if it hasn't been surrounded yet.  But not just surrounded, led or trailed, because it could be the `foo` in an already tagged `<tag>foo bar</tag>`.  Something like this `"(?<!(\\w|>))+" + word + "(?!(\\w|<))+"` will match only if `word` doesn't already have a leading `>`, a trailing `<`, and isn't in the middle of another word.  (I'll admit, I'm not great at regex, so I'm sure this could be better)